# Hibernate @OneToMany association tries to set a null FK value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have the following simple example. When it runs, I see the QuoteRequest object being generated with auto-generated id. Next, I see the Accidents object being generated, but quote_request_id that's being inserted is null, so I get an error:

***Column 'quote_request_id' cannot be null***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Quotes")
public class QuoteRequest
{
    public QuoteRequest(){}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "quote_request_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long QuoteRequestId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quoteRequest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "accidents_id")
    private Accidents[] accidents;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Accidents")
public class Accidents
{
    public Accidents()
    {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "accidents_id")
    private long AccidentId;


    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private Float amount;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "quote_request_id", nullable = false)
    private QuoteRequest quoteRequest;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Why isn't it inserting the newly generated ID into the accidents column?

Comment: It looks strange. By your config, when `Accidents` get inserted, it should have `quote_request_id` insert together.  May I know which version of Hibernate you are using?  And, more important: for the `Accidents` object you created, have you actually setup its `quoteRequest` correctly? (I wish you are only setting the `accidents` on `QuoteRequest` side, but forgot the `quoteRequest` on the `Accidents` side, as the latter is the side that owns the relationship).  One OT issue: You should name it `Accident` instead of `Accidents`, as it represent one accident only

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 4.3.9.Final

I am not assigning quoteRequest on Accidents explicitly. I am creating Accidents, adding them to QuoteRequest. When creating Accidents, I don't set the quoteRequest property. Should I be doing anything with that? Do I need to have a bi-directional relationship?

Good call on the naming. I didn't come up with it, but I am stuck with it now :)

Comment: Then that's the problem.  Will give an answer to you

Comment: Ok great. Another note, I serialize this from a JSON object. So my QuoteRequest and Accidents are auto-populated from JSON data

Comment: mappedBy = "quoteRequest" means it is bi-directional relationship and the Accidents owns the relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When creating Accidents, I don't set the quoteRequest property. Should I be doing anything with that? Do I need to have a bi-directional relationship?

This is the reason.

First, "Do I need to have a bi-directional relationship?". Well, you are the only one that can tell.  However, you are already having bi-directional relationship.  By the way you set that up, `Accident` side is owning the relationship.  That means, for the DB Column `Accident.quote_req_id` is relying on the field `Accident.quoteRequest`.  As you have not populate that field, Hibernate is assuming that is a null.  Hence it is inserting null.  All expected behavior.

In short, you should make sure `QuoteRequest.accident` and `Accident.quoteRequest` is consistent, for example:

```
class QuoteRequest {
    private List<Accident> accidents = new ArrayList<>();  // I prefer List or Set

    public void setAccidents(List<Accident> accidents) {
        this.accidents.clear();
        if (accidents != null) {
            // intentionally keeping another list, to be defensive and not
            // affected by subsequent change in the caller's list
            this.accidents = this.accidents.addAll(accidents);
            for (Accident accident:accidents) {
                accident.setQuoteRequest(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Accident {
    private QuoteRequest quoteRequest;
    public setQuoteRequest(QuoteRequest quoteRequest) {
        // there will be something more...
        this.quoteRequest = quoteRequest;
    }
}
```

This is just a very basic example on what it will look like.  In short, you need `Accident.quoteRequest` set with appropriate value.  There are still lots of issue in above implementation and I will leave it for you (e.g. when you previously has `accidents` set and now replaced with another list)

Answer (score 1):

First, change the `@OneToMany` from using an array to using a `List` instead:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "quoteRequest", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderColumn(name = "accidents_id")
private List<Accidents> accidents = new ArrayList()<>;
```

Make sure you set both sides of the associations:

```
QuoteRequest quoteRequest = ...
Accidents accidents = ...

quoteRequest.getAccidents().add(accident);
accident.setQuoteRequest(quoteRequest);
```